# Restkit-Core data: Duplicate objects in ObjectStore and Backend when post

Tags: core-data, restkit, duplicate-data

I have a problem when using Restkit (0.10.3)+core data on an iOS 5.0 app. I have a entity ToDo mapped as follow:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* map = [self mappingInObjectStore];

[map mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
 @"id"          ,   @"todoID"      ,
 @"message"     ,   @"detail"       ,
 @"created_at"  ,   @"createdAt"    ,
 @"updated_at"  ,   @"updatedAt"   ,
 @"public_location",@"publicLocation",   
 nil];

map.primaryKeyAttribute = @"todoID";
[map mapKeyPath:@"location" toRelationship:@"location" withMapping:[TDLocation mapping]];
```

TDLocation is a simple entity with long,lat, ...

I created an TODO object using [TDTodo object] method and set all needed data, with the exception of todoID (because it will filled by the backend). Later I do the post:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:todo usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.onDidLoadResponse= ^(RKResponse *response){
        if (response.isOK || response.isCreated) {
            id parsedData = [response parsedBody:nil];
            todo.todoID = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [[parsedData valueForKeyPath:@"acceptedTodo.id"] intValue]]; //just get the assigned id from backend
        }
        [loader cancel];
    }; 
}];
```

Up to here, everything is ok. If I do [TDTodo allObjects], I get the posted todo with the assigned id. But later I made a get of todo list and I retrieve two more objects TDTodo containing the same info that the posted todo, so I do [TDTodo allObjects]

```
{todoID: 1, ...}//posted todo
{todoID: 1, ...} // from the backend with the same info and id that the posted todo
{todoID: 2, ...} // from the backend with the same info that the posted todo, but diff id.
```

In conclusion, I have 3 (three) duplicated instance of the same object in the object Store. I searched for this problem, but I couldn't find a working solution.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**
I solved one part of the problem: "duplicate creation of entities in the back end". This was produce by trying to cancel the response/loader, in concrete this instruction:

`[loader cancel];`

Also I tried:

```
[response.request cancel];
[response.request.delegate = nil;
```

but this produces also the duplicates. So removing this instructions fix that part of the problem.

However, there is still the duplicates in the objectStore:

```
{todoID: 1, ...}//posted todo`
{todoID: 1, ...} // from the backend with the same info and id that the posted todo`\
```

How I can solve this? I tried all solution that I found in the web :-(

Cheers.